# TestStack.White Get all Tabs

Tags: c#, ui-automation, teststack

is there a way to get all elements of a specific type of a window?
In my case, I want to get all tabs of the page to filter it afterwards by which has the greater Y-coord.

This method:
`Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.TabItems.Tab>(TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders.SearchCriteria.All)`
only returns the first element it finds.

Thank you and regards,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SearchCriteria.ByControlType

```
IUIItem[] items = window.GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.ByControlType(ControlType.Tab));
```

Using Linq...

```
using System.Linq;

...

IUIItem[] items = window.GetMultiple(SearchCriteria.All).OfType<Tab>();
```